# Mix dots and named arguments in function calling aes for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse

I'm trying to create a wrapper around the `ggplot` that allows me to add some aesthetics like the x variable or color but always prefills `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` without having to work with quoted variable names.

Since ggplot2 cannot use tidy evaluation I have to use NSE for this but I'm stuck, the information I could find [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Creating-a-new-geom) and inspecting some functions made me try things like `unlist(...)` and working with `match.call()`. but they only throw different errors.

In the below function I'd basically like to be able to call `ci_plot()` or for example `ci_plot(color = cyl)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)


ci_plot <- function(data, ...) {
  ggplot(data, aes(..., y = y, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))  
}

mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(x = map(data, ~mean_se(.x$hwy))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  ci_plot() + 
  geom_pointrange()
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458526/r-pass-variable-column-indices-to-ggplot2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I found shadow's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699448/modify-aes-list-outside-ggplot-function) and figured out how to adapt it for my purpose.
I'll try to outline the solution as much as I understand it.

```
ci_plot <- function(data, ...) {
  # Create a list of unevaluated parameters,
  # removing the first two, which are the function itself and data.
  arglist <- as.list(match.call()[-c(1,2)]) 

  # We can add additional parameters to the list using substitute
  arglist$ymin = substitute(ymin)
  arglist$y    = substitute(y)
  arglist$ymax = substitute(ymax)

  # I suppose this allows ggplot2 to recognize that it needs to quote the arguments
  myaes <- structure(arglist, class="uneval")

  # And this quotes the arguments?
  myaes <- ggplot2:::rename_aes(myaes)

  ggplot(data, myaes)  
}
```

That function allows me to write the code like this

```
mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(x = map(data, ~mean_se(.x$hwy))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  ci_plot(x = cyl, color = manufacturer) + 
  geom_pointrange()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options, depending on how you want the user to be able to pass the variables to the function.

**Using strings and `aes_string`**

You could have the user give variables via strings.  In this case, you want that `...` in `aes_string` and then add a separate `aes` layer for the "fixed" variables.

Your data manipulation code was returning all `NA` for me, so this example is simpler.  I fixed the  `y` variable to be `cty`.

```
ci_plot = function(data, ...) {
     ggplot(data, aes_string(...) )  +
          aes( y = cty )
}

ci_plot(data = mpg, x = "displ", color = "class") +
     geom_point()
```

**Using tildes and `aes_`**

An alternative is to have the user use tildes for variables when using the function.  In that case, `aes_` can be used for both fixed and changeable variables.

```
ci_plot2 = function(data, ...) {
     ggplot(data, aes_(..., y = ~cty ) ) 
}

ci_plot2(data = mpg, x = ~displ, color = ~class) +
     geom_point()
```

The resulting plot from both functions:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. However I was looking for ways to keep the syntax the same as for other vanilla ggplot2 functions, without quotes (I probably didn't stress it enough). I managed to sole the issue now and posted an answer if you are interested.